# How to read file stream as PDF from Amazon S3 and display in browser

Tags: playframework

We use the following code to read a PDF file from Amazon S3.

```
 S3Object object = client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
 InputStream is = object.getObjectContent();
 Results.ok(is)
```

However the PDF is rendered as blank.

Could you please provide a code snippet on play with angular to display or render the stream as PDF in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the content-type?

```
return Results.ok(is).as("application/pdf");
```